# Always return to beginning of ZSH history after search?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-zle

ZSH history search is quite helpful, but one nit I have with it is that it moves your 'history pointer' to whereever your last search was. This is irritating if I'm typing a common command, and get landed at a spot in my history from weeks ago:

```sh
> ls foo/bar/[up arrow]
> ls foo/bar/baz/weeks/ago  #(whoops!)
> [ctrl + u]                #(clear it out, start over)
> [up arrow]                #(try again...)
> ls more/weeks/ago         #(search starts from that weeks-ago point)
```

I'm using the `oh-my-zsh` defaults of `up-line-or-beginning-search` and `up-line-or-beginning-search` for `up-arrow` and `down-arrow` respectively. I've checked `man zshcontrib` and `man zshzle`, but the documentation doesn't seem to address this behavior.

Short of shortening the size of the history (something I should probably do anyways), is there a way to make history search always start from the beginning (most recent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty line before trying again. This will reset [`$HISTNO`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-HISTNO).

Alternatively, use [`zsh-autocomplete`’s history menu & history search](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete). They always start from the most recent item.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. This will probably work for me, but one could combine this with [`precmd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html) to get the behavior I described.

Comment: No, that wouldn’t work. `precmd` is called before initializing a new command line, so, only after executing the previous command line.

Comment: @LukeAbel I added another option to my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: ‍♂️ you're right - I forgot my own question. Thanks for the suggestion.